# How to get my code to show all mathematical steps in C

Tags: c

I wrote this code to find the GCD of 2 whole numbers using Euclid's algorithm but I want to show the steps it's doing when I run it. Is that possible, if so how should I modify what I've already done. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
GCD (int a, int b)
{
  if (a == b)
    {
      return a;
    }
  else
    {
      if (a > b)
    return GCD (a - b, b);

      else
    return GCD (a, b - a);
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  int a, b;
  printf
    ("Please enter 2 numbers separated by a comma: ");
  scanf ("%d,%d", &a, &b);
  int GCD (int a, int b);
  printf ("\nGCD of %d and %d is %d", a, b, GCD (a, b));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There’s no automagic solution: you’ll need to manually add `printf` statements at all relevant locations inside `GCD`.

Comment: You'll see quite a lot by printing the arguments on entry to the function. Good luck with large values when using repeated subtraction instead of modulus.

Comment: or run the code in a debugger and step through everything it does

Comment: Note that `int GCD (int a, int b);` inside `main` looks like a function declaration.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I tried adding printf statements but they wouldn't show. I'll keep trying but thank you !!

Comment: Probably turning your warnings up would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to understand what your code is doing you can use a debugger like gdb.
but there is another way if you don't know how to use a debugger or you just don't like it and that is printing the values where it can show us some information. I think the code below can show you what you like to see.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
GCD (int a, int b)
{
  if (a == b)
  {
    printf("they are equal so we found the gcd!");
    return a;
  }
  else
  {
    if (a > b)
    {
      printf("now we calculate gcd of %d and %d\n",a-b,b);
      return GCD (a - b, b);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("now we calculate gcd of %d and %d\n",a,b-a);
      return GCD (a, b - a);    
    }
  }
}

int
main ()
{
  int a, b;
  printf("Please enter 2 numbers separated by a comma: ");
  scanf ("%d,%d", &a, &b);
  int GCD (int a, int b);
  printf ("\nGCD of %d and %d is %d", a, b, GCD (a, b));
  return 0;
}
```

if you want your code to calculate gcd faster I recommend reading this  article
https://www.javatpoint.com/gcd-of-two-numbers-in-c